# Dynamically summing table values - Microsoft Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I am creating a spreadsheet that models the sale of some single family homes.

I have built a sale schedule that says X of the homes are to be sold per month, and I am then looking to multiply that X number by the appropriate values (the values are not the same, and range from $300,000-$450,000)

Say I am supposed to sell 4 in the first month, 4 in the second month, and 4 in the last month, and the sale values are as follows:

1 – 300k

2 – 300k

3 – 300k

4 – 350k

5 – 350k

6 – 350k

7 – 400k

8 – 400k

9 – 400k

10 – 450k

11 – 450k

12 – 450k

Can I create a formula that looks at the number of homes sold in the first month (4), then add up the values 300k + 300k +300k +350k (representing the first 4 homes on the list)

The second month should be relatively similar. 4 homes are to be sold that month, however I would now like to add up home 5 – home 8 values (350k + 350k + 350k + 400k)

And for the 3rd month of 4 homes sold: 400k + 400k + 400k + 450k.

Is there a function that can dynamically add differing table values based on some type of criteria?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will do what you need.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$B$12,--(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$12,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM($E$2:E2))),0))))-SUM($F$1:F1)
```

This is an array type formula and so the references need to be limited to just the data set.

`ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&SUM($E$2:E2))` creates an array of numbers.  In `F2` the array is `{1,2,3,4}` then `F3` it becomes `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` and so on.

The match tries to find the values in `$A$1:$A$12` one at a time, it either returns a number or an error.

When error the SUMPRODUCT ignores the corresponding value in `$B$1:$B$12` otherwise it sums the value.

Because in `F3` we will sum all values 1 - 8 we need to remove the already summed value from `F2`.  Thus the `SUM($F$1:F1)`.

[image]

Comment: that is very helpful.... it certainly works! Thanks for your help, the description is extremely helpful as well.